# Webpage changes when I run it

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to design a webpage using Asp.net and CSS in Visual Studio 2010. the problem is simple but i have no idea how to fix it. Im creating a header in my page,  this header is a div, its linked to my stylesheet for coloring. I put an image in the div, and i added a label. Now after some time to put the image in the middle of the div and text under it, when i run the website, the Label leaves the div completely and sits outside. How do i fix this? and for future reference, what technique or method do i follow so that the webpage before running always looks the same after running? I've decided to create a stylesheet for every page and put all my styles in there.

Sorry, here it is.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="LoginStyleSheet.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="HeaderDiv">
    <img alt="" class="Logo"  longdesc="http://localhost:17260/MECIT_Logo.png" 
        src="MECIT_Logo.png" />
        <asp:Label CssClass="Title" ID="WelcomeLabel" runat="server" Text="SSS"> 
         </asp:label>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        </div>  
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>


 body 
 {
background-color:Gray;
 }
 .HeaderDiv
  {
background-color: #0099FF;
height: 121px;
  }
 .Logo
  {
 position:absolute;
 left:40%;
  }
  .Title
  {
 position:absolute;
 left:38%;
 bottom:83%;
 font-size:xx-large;
 font-family:Cambria;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:Navy;
 width: 336px;
 }
```

Comment: Please post your html and css

Comment: Dude, we can't see HOW you're doing this. How do you expect anyone to help.

Comment: I see you have a  fixed height on `.HeaderDiv`, what is the height of the image you've added inside the div?

Comment: Why are the `.Title` and `.Logo` ID's set to an absolute position? Maybe if you set the `.Logo`'s `position` to `position:relative;` that could help with the problem.

Comment: I havent added any height for the image, just centered it in the middle, and added the label under it. I made the height of the div enough to fit both of them.

Comment: putting the position to relative made the title and logo go to left way too much.

Comment: Also noticed something now, when i run the web and click "inspect element" , expanding the inspection tab up and down moves the label with it, does this tell you anything?

Comment: Yes it would seem your `bottom:83%` is using the bottom of the screen. I would agree with @DomenikVanBuskirk, set your `.Title` to relative and reposition it. I found using % to position items is a pain. Using `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` is a better way of positioning items centrally to a users screen.

Comment: Hey Vletech, that worked, but the label only positions itself after i run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are absolutely positioning the elements inside the container, all this can be handled with margins and alignment.  Here is my suggestion:

[Click here to view the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNCodeMonkey/WFKgH/)

CSS:

```
 body 
 {
background-color:Gray;
 }
 .HeaderDiv
  {
background-color: #0099FF;
height: 121px;
    text-align:center;
  }
 .Logo
  {
margin:5 auto;
  }
  .Title
  {
 font-size:xx-large;
 font-family:Cambria;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:Navy;
 width: 336px;
 }​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="HeaderDiv">
    <img alt="" class="Logo"  longdesc="http://localhost:17260/MECIT_Logo.png" 
    src="http://www.mecit.edu.om/images/MECIT_Logo.png" /><br />
    //Used a <span> for the Label, as I believe that is what it renders as
    <span class="Title" id="WelcomeLabel">Some Title</span>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        </div>
```

Comment: You are awesome...thank you. I will learn all about margins now.

Comment: Just one more question if you dont mind, I added another div under the HeaderDiv, called it FooterDiv, i created it in the css file and added the same attributes as the HeaderDiv, when i do this in jstfiddle, it works, but it does nothing in my program, stays empty, even though its basically a copy of the HeaderDiv.

Comment: Could you post a fiddle of your HTML and CSS please?